# Set multiple div elements to "position: fixed" at the bottom of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 div on my page. I want to set those 4 div at bottom, so that those div stay at bottom even when there are scrollbar.

This is my HTML.

```
<div id="content">
1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br />
Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit <br />
Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit <br />
Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit <br />
Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit <br />
Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit <br />
Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit <br />

Long Dummy content.
</div>
<div class="footerdiv">Footer - scroll 1</div>
<div class="footerdiv">Footer - scroll2</div>
<div class="footerdiv">Footer - scroll 3</div>
<div class="footerdiv">Footer - scroll4</div>
```

And my Css

```
.footerdiv {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

It is setting my div at bottom, But all the bottom div are overlapping.
I want to show them side by side by keeping all 4 div at bottom.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow4vg27c/2/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than positioning each element at the bottom, wrap the elements and set the parent element's `position` to `fixed` and position it at the bottom.

In doing so, the `.footerdiv` elements are still in the normal flow, and they can be positioned beside each other.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t6tqjywd/)

```
.footer-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.footer-container .footerdiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had actually used 4 div's with same DIV id.

This is what you had to do-

```
<div class="footerdiv">
    <div>Footer - scroll 1</div>
    <div>Footer - scroll2</div>
    <div>Footer - scroll 3</div>
    <div>Footer - scroll4</div>
</div>
```

and set css to 100%, let it take up the horizontal space of the page-

```
.footerdiv {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Have a look at the **working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mta8zxp9) on JS fiddle**.

Hope it helps :) Happy coding!

Comment: OP never had same id on the footer div's, he had same class though, which is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Set an id for each div and refer to each div that way.

```
<div class="footerdiv" id = "d1">Footer - scroll 1</div>
<div class="footerdiv" id = "d2">Footer - scroll2</div>
<div class="footerdiv" id = "d3">Footer - scroll 3</div>
<div class="footerdiv" id = "d4">Footer - scroll4</div>
```

Then you can say:

```
.footerdiv {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
#d1 {
    left: 100px;
}
#d2 {
    left: 200px;
}
#d3 {
    left: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a table? You can create a new column for each one of your elements.

```
<table class="footerdiv">
  <tr>
    <td>Footer - scroll 1</td>
    <td>Footer - scroll 2</td>
    <td>Footer - scroll 3</td>
    <td>Footer - scroll 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them in footer like this. Here is fixed version:
https://jsfiddle.net/4dq215h4/2/

and change css to this:

```
.footerdiv {
background: #0070FF;
line-height: 2;
text-align: center;
color: #042E64;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #84BAFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #00214B;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
width:100px;
}
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:10px;
}
```